# Adding an index and specified number to an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing

I am making a program that removes a number from the index that the user provides from the array, displays the new array, then asks the user to insert a number at whatever index they choose. The first part of this program works fine when it comes to removing an index, but I am having trouble with adding an index and number. For example, if the NEW array after the user deletes the number from index 5 is: 12 34 45 2 8 16 180 182 22, which is correct if you remember that arrays start at 0, then they request for example index 5 to be added again with the number 78, it gets messed up. It displays 12 34 45 2 78 8 16 180 182 22 (and then it also outputs the number -858993460 for some reason?) SO the problem basically is that it adds the new index and number one index BEFORE it is supposed to. Im sorry if this sounds so confusing but I have been stuck on it for hours. Thank you!

```
//This program demos basic arrays

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int CAP = 10;

int main()
{
    int size;
    int list[CAP] = { 12, 34, 45, 2, 8, 10, 16, 180, 182, 22 };
    size = 10;
    int i, delIndex, addIndex, newInt = 0;

    cout << "Your list is: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < CAP; i++)
    {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    } 

//Deleting an index

cout << "\nPlease enter index to delete from: ";
cin >> delIndex;

for (i = delIndex; i <= 10; i++)
{
    list[i] = list[i + 1];

}

cout << "The index position you specified has been deleted." << endl;
cout << "The new array is: " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
{
    cout << list[i] << endl;
}

//Adding an index

cout << "\nNow, please enter the index position to add to: " << endl;
cin >> addIndex;
cout << "\nEnter the number to add to the index: " << endl;
cin >> newInt;

for (i = size - 1; i >= addIndex - 1; i--)
{
    list[i + 1] = list[i];
}
        list[addIndex - 1] = newInt;
        size++;

    cout << "The number has been added at the specified index position." << 
endl;
    cout << "The new array is: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i = delIndex; i <= 10; i++) {list[i] = list[i + 1];}` -- This loop writes to items that are out-of-bounds of the array.  Second, arrays cannot be resized, so "removing elements" or "adding elements" is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: Then I am not sure how to word it. If you test my program, the user is able to request the the index to have a number removed. Those were my instructions, I didn't make this up.

Comment: It is not "working fine".  You are just lucky it works.  The array has 10 items, yet you are accessing items well beyond `list[9]`.  You are accessing index 10 and 11, thus creating a buffer overrun and *undefined behavior* occurs.

Comment: Change `for (i = delIndex; i <= 10; i++)` to `for (i = delIndex; i < 9; i++)`

Comment: @Ishpreet -- `for (i = delIndex; i < 10; i++)` -- That still writes out of bounds on the last iteration.

Comment: My instructions are to delete an element in an array, which (I think i've done but I guess I really haven't) sorry if im messing up on terminology here i'm very new in c++. I am now having troubles inserting an element into the array.

Comment: @user8930130 Doesn't matter what your instructions are -- the loop I pointed out is not correct. You need to fix it -- don't be surprised if your teacher takes your code, runs it, and a crash happens on that loop.

Comment: So in that loop not being correct, the second half of my program that then ADDS a number to the array is also not correct?

Comment: Anything after that loop is null and void due to the buffer overrun.  The point really is do **you** see what the issue is with that loop, instead of me or someone else just telling you it's wrong?

Comment: I am not sure I see it, I replaced i <= 10 with i <= CAP. CAP is my constant int that equals 10. I am not sure if this is what you mean.

Comment: What are the valid indices of an array with `n` items?  An array with `n` items has indices ranging from `0` to `n-1`, meaning the indices are `0` to `9`.  These are basics of C++, and not knowing these basics will be a hindrance in writing correct C++ programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with handling `size` variable in your code.

Following is corrected code. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/Oclcsz):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int CAP = 10;

int main()
{
    int size;
    int list[CAP] = { 12, 34, 45, 2, 8, 10, 16, 180, 182, 22 };
    size = CAP;
    int i, delIndex, addIndex, newInt = 0;

    cout << "Your list is: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    } 

    //Deleting an index

    cout << "\nPlease enter index to delete from: ";
    cin >> delIndex;

    for (i = delIndex; i < size; i++)
    {
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    }
    size--;
    cout << "The index position you specified has been deleted." << endl;
    cout << "The new array is: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }

    //Adding an index

    cout << "\nNow, please enter the index position to add to: " << endl;
    cin >> addIndex;
    cout << "\nEnter the number to add to the index: " << endl;
    cin >> newInt;

    for (i = size - 1; i >= addIndex; i--)
    {
        list[i + 1] = list[i];
    }
    list[addIndex] = newInt;
    size++;

    cout << "The number has been added at the specified index position." <<endl;
    cout << "The new array is: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** Since we are talking about *index* and not *position* in the array, so it is treated as `0` based and element is added at *index* `addIndex`, not at `addIndex-1`.

Comment: This seems to have fixed my program but there is now a new error that is pretty minuscule that maybe you can help me with. When I add the number 675, for example, into the index spot number 3, it does input it in the correct position, however the number "10" which comes after the inputted number (675) repeats itself and appears twice. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @user8930130 Corrected now. The problem was with loop condition part. It should be `i >= addIndex;` not `i > addIndex;`. Now Corrected in answer.

Comment: This works perfectly. Wish everyone here was as helpful as you, and as to the point as you. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are some loopholes in your program, that you can improve.

1. You are declaring a constant (**CAP**), but the array size is changing, so point doing that.
2. You are printing the array multiple times, its better to use a function, and call it every time, when you need to print the entire array.
3. You are using literals like `10`, in some sections of the program. It is advisable to use the same variable like `size` or `CAP` instead of `10` to improve readability.
4. You can even put insert & delete in functions so that they can be called multiple times.

This is a sample working code, you can take the idea of that. I haven't implemented **Step 4**, I hope you can do that easily,

[**LIVE CODE**](https://ideone.com/4KRJcc)

**Working Code**

```
//This program demos basic arrays
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int CAP = 10;

void printArr(int list[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < CAP; i++)
        cout << list[i] << " ";
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int list[CAP] = { 12, 34, 45, 2, 8, 10, 16, 180, 182, 22 };
    int i, delIndex, addIndex, newInt = 0;
    cout << "Your list is: " << endl;
    printArr(list);

    //Deleting an index
    cout << "\nPlease enter index(0 indexed based) to delete from: ";
    cin >> delIndex;
    for (i = delIndex; i < CAP - 1; i++)
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    CAP--;
    cout << "The index position you specified has been deleted." << endl;
    cout << "The new array is: " << endl;
    printArr(list);

    //Adding an index
    cout << "\nNow, please enter the index position(0 indexed based) to add to: " << endl;
    cin >> addIndex;
    cout << "\nEnter the number to add to the index: " << endl;
    cin >> newInt;
    for (i = CAP; i > addIndex; i--)
        list[i] = list[i-1];        
    list[addIndex] = newInt;
    CAP++;
    cout << "The number has been added at the specified index position." << endl;
    cout << "The new array is: " << endl;
    printArr(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I put this program into visual studio, I get the error message "const int CAP = 10, expression must be a modifiable value". Do you know why this is?

Comment: @Ishpreet This just replacing the element at the index `addIndex - 1`. Not _adding_. Have a close watch on the out put. Also you can see `22` two times at the end of output.

Comment: @cse Yeah I missed that, Updated the code as well as working link. Good catch

Comment: @user8930130 You cannot change the value of a **`constant`** Use variable instead. Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07x6b05d.aspx)